# How to change the directory by default in my Terminal? (command line)

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

how can I register a specific folder to be the folder by default when I open the Terminal?
For now, it is `~`, and I always have to do `cd ../../Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` to use the Terminal with my project.

Can I make this "htdocs" the folder by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put

```
cd /my/starting/directory
```

Into ~/.bashrc

Which will be executed each time you start a shell.

Comment: thanks, can you show the procedure to "add" into the file?

Comment: You can use any text editor and just append it to the end. If the file doesn't exist you can create it. Also,  if you didn't know, '~' refers to your home directory, so /home/<your username>/.bashrc is where you will find it.

Comment: If you just want a one liner you can run: echo "cd /my/directory/" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: I tried but it does not work : `vim .bashrc` , I get the PATH with all the paths like usr/bin etc. I added my line : `cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs` when I open a new window in the Terminal, the folder by default is still `~`. I also tried with echo but the result is the same.

Comment: The commands in ~/.bashrc are simply commands run when you start a new terminal. So make sure that your command 'cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs' works in general. What operating system are you using? Are you sure you don't mean 'cd ~/Applications/MAMP/htdocs'? Don't forget the ~ in 'vim ~/.bashrc' either.

Comment: It sounds like you might be using mac? Try adding the line to ~/.bash_profile instead.

Comment: still nothing. I also switched off and on my computer, still the same path to `~`.

Comment: Can you tell me which operating system you use? Did you try ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: ok now it works! But doing "cd" alone to go back points to "~". But it's ok. Only if you have the solution about this, I could still open a new window each time if I want to go back to htdocs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the bash file .. `~/.bashrc` and add `cd /go/to/my/directory`